# Java reading CSV file that contains Strings and Integers adding them to arraylist and then instantiating arraylist

Tags: java, csv, parsing

SO, here goes my choppy explanation of my choppy title.

I have a csv file, and it contains, at the moment

```
id,name,hp,atk,def,desc
1,Man,10,5,5,A man
2,Woman,10,5,5,A woman
3,Goblin,15,7,3,A goblin ack!
```

I am trying to take the information from this csv file, send it to an ArrayList, instantiate the ArrayList using the Constructor I have for NPCs so that later on I can use these NPCs as objects -- if that makes sense.

I think I have like some of this done already, I just don't know how to read integers from the CSV file.

```
public class NPCLoader {
    
    private static final String dir = "./data/npcs.csv";
    public static ArrayList<NPCHandler> npcs = new ArrayList<NPCHandler>();
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        loadNpcs();
    }

    private static void loadNpcs() {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(dir)));
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] n = line.split(",");
            NPCHandler npc = new NPCHandler(n[0], n[1], n[2], n[3], n[4], n[5]);//issue is here, it wants me to change my constructor to String String String String String when it needs to be int String int int int String
            npcs.add(npc);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my constructor for the NPCHandler if you need to see it

```
public class NPCHandler {
    
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int hp;
    private int atk;
    private int def;
    private String desc;
    
    
    public NPCHandler(int id, String name, int hp, int atk, int def, String desc) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.hp = hp;
        this.atk = atk;
        this.def = def;
        this.desc = desc;
    }
//Get setters below
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that since you're loading a csv file, every variables are considered strings.

The solution could be to parse some of them to Integer, something like that:

```
NPCHandler npc = new NPCHandler(Integer.parseInt(n[0]), 
                                n[1], 
                                Integer.parseInt(n[2]),
                                Integer.parseInt(n[3]),
                                Integer.parseInt(n[4]),
                                n[5]);
```

[Reference for string conversion](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-to-int)